# Symfony5: form for self-referencing many-to-many

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many, symfony-forms, symfony5

In a Symfony5 application, how can we utilize the form-component to correctly set up a self-referencing, many-to-many relationship?

Note: this is purely about the form-side of things, Doctrine is already happy.

Let's say we have a "Person"-entity, and these Person-instances host guests, who are also Persons:

```php
#[Entity(repositoryClass: PersonRepository::class)]
class Person
{
    #[Id]
    #[GeneratedValue]
    #[Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    private int $id;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 255)]
    private string $firstName;

    #[Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 255)]
    private string $lastName;

    /** @var Collection<Person> */
    #[ManyToMany(targetEntity: self::class, inversedBy: 'guestsHosted')]
    private Collection $hosts;

    /** @var Collection<Person> */
    #[ManyToMany(targetEntity: self::class, mappedBy: 'hosts')]
    private Collection $guestsHosted;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fellowshipHosts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->fellowsHosted = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // getters/setters ommitted for brevity


    public function addHost(self $host): self
    {
    }

    public function removeHost(self $host): self
    {
    }

    public function addGuestsHosted(self $guestHosted): self
    {
    }

    public function removeGuestsHosted(self $guestsHosted): self
    {
    }
```

What I would like to achieve is a form with a collection of addable/removable rows, where the user then is able to add a row, select an existing other person as their host, add another row, select another person, and so on. A simple mockup:

[image]

How do I achieve this using Symfony's form-component? What I have in there now does not work due to recursion on the same form-type:

```php
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder           
            ->add('firstName', null, [])
            ->add('lastName', null, [])            
            ->add('hosts', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => self::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'required' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Person::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

NB: I've built similar UIs like this in the past and know about the little dance involving `form.vars.prototype` and hooking up the JS to that. Where I'm lost is how to map this association on the form-level, so that I get a dropdown of all Persons, and map that into the `$hosts` property of the entity.

Comment: Create another form type called `HostFormType` and add a ChoiceType for your dropdown within that (you will need to work out the logic to populate the dropdown)... Then make the "hosts" field's **"entry_type => HostFormType::class"**. Hope that gives you some help and direction.

Comment: I like this. However, setting `HostFormType`'s `data_class => Person::class` and the choice-field's name to the property-name inside `Person`, Symfony complains with: **The property "hosts" in class "App\Entity\Person" can be defined with the methods "addHost()", "removeHost()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable.** which doesn't tell me a lot right now. Any clues? Would you care to flesh out an answer?

Comment: I see @Hast has you covered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bossman's comment is pretty correct, but just in case you want to do it with a single form type, I'd do something like this:

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder           
            ->add('firstName', null, [])
            ->add('lastName', null, []);

        if (!$options['is_host']) {            
            ->add('hosts', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => self::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false, 'is_host' => true],
                'required' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Person::class,
            'is_host' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Basically what I'm doing here is preventing recursion by explicitly passing 'is_host' to the form options, which indicates whether this is a sub-entity, and then I'm building 'hosts' form field only for the root entity.

If you want to select among existing hosts, use EntityType:

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        // You'll be able to use this later in the 'query_builder' option
        $personId = $options['person_id'];

        $builder
            ->add('firstName', null, [])
            ->add('lastName', null, [])
            ->add('hosts', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => EntityType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false, 'class' => Person::class],
                'required' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ])
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Person::class,
        ]);

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('person_id', ['int', 'null']);
    }
}
```

It's important to remember the following:

1. You will have to pass current person id as `person_id` options of the form (or null for new entries). You may also retrieve this value from the $builder variable if you want.
2. Modify 'query_builder' in the EntityType options for your needs, e.g. don't exclude current (root) person from the hosts list, etc.
3. This approach **MIGHT** lead to multiple DB queries (1 per each collection item), but I'm not sure about it right now. If it does, you should find a solution for this problem by yourself.

Comment: Nice, I haven't seen passing around options like that yet. Sadly, this simply embeds the full form in the little sub-form rows, prompting the user to type in firstname, lastname, etc, effectively creating a new entity rather than selecting an existing one. Any hints on this? Perhaps I need an unmapped field of ChoiceType, and use a transformer to pull out the selected IDs of Persons, then retrieve those entities and establish the association manually...?

Comment: Well, then you should use CollectionType with entry_type=EntityType. Updated the answer with a small example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working exactly as expected. I wasn't aware of this approach to creating a collection of embedded forms "inline", i.e. not via a separate form type.